# How to get all information with all images in site

Tags: image, bash, curl, download, wget

I want to get all information with all images, is there any simple way to use bash on Mac? I want to get data as below:

```
"product": "8020"
"simage": "/uploadfile/201281616171259157_.GIF"
"image": "/uploadfile/201281616171259157.GIF"
"name": "Taipei 101"

"product": "8019"
"simage": "/uploadfile/201432010288118198_.jpg"
"image": "/uploadfile/201432010288118198.jpg"
"name": "TianTan"
```

This doesn't work, also I need product and name and so on, there are not in src attribute...

```
baseurl=$(echo $url | egrep -o "https?://[a-z.]+")

curl --silent $url | egrep -o "src=[^>]*(\.jpg|\.gif|\.png)" | sed 's/src=\"\(.*\)/\1/g' > /tmp/$$.list
sed -i "s|^/|$baseurl/|" /tmp/$$.list

while read filename;
do
    curl -s -O "$baseurl/$filename"
done < /tmp/$$.list
```

The site contents of product.asp?cxsort=10001

```
....
<ul id="small" >
    <li><a href="product.asp?cxsort=10001">Military1</a></li>
    <li><a href="product.asp?cxsort=10021">Military2</a></li>
    <li><a href="product.asp?cxsort=10101">Military3</a></li>
....
</ul>

....
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td>Product:8020</td>
        <td><div class="set"><img  src="/uploadfile/201281616171259157_.GIF" width="94" height="69"  style="display:block" class="/uploadfile/201281616171259157.GIF" alt="TianTan" /></div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
....
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td>Product:8019</td>
        <td><div class="Set"><img  src="/uploadfile/201432010288118198_.jpg" width="94" height="69"  style="display:block" class="/uploadfile/201432010288118198.jpg" alt="Taipei 101" /></div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
....
```

Comment: Of course, I tried but no result what I want to.

Comment: I'm going to state the obligatory "don't parse HTML with regular expressions". There are tons of decent libraries out there that make this fast. Consider strongly using them and not reinventing the wheel.

Comment: please give me more detail information, I try to use curl, wget with awk or see, but I am not sure what them are:(

Comment: hint: xmlstarlet, xmllint.

Comment: I checked xmlstarlet, I don't think they are easy:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this :

```
sed -n '
/Product/ {
        s/[ \t]*<[^>]*>//g
        s/Product:\([0-9]*\)/"product": "\1"/p
        n
        s/.*img  *src="\([^"]*\)".*class="\([^"]*\).*alt="\([^"]*\).*/"simage": "\1"\n"image": "\2"\n"name": "\3"\n/p
}
' file.html
```

It works with your example and should do the trick on your html if the code related to product and image is always structured the same way.

But a web-scraping library like BeautifulSoup in python would be a better choice.

A BeautifulSoup python code looks like this :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

f = file('file.html', 'r')
soup = BeautifulSoup(f)

all_img = soup.find_all('img')
for img in all_img:
        print '%s : %s' % (img['alt'], img['src'])
```

Comment: I checked BeautifulSoup, it seems like simple, can you prompt me a simplest py file to use BeautifulSou? I still in trying, but no successful until now....